# What to do with the [blueprint] tag?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

I just changed [blueprint](/questions/tagged/blueprint) to [blueprint-css](/questions/tagged/blueprint-css) for a number of questions about the [Blueprint CSS framework](http://blueprintcss.org). The rest of the questions with that tag seem to describe some other things, like:

- [Java BluePrints](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/blueprints)
- A Python library called [Blueprint](https://github.com/devstructure/blueprint)
- One or two other obscure topics

There are only about a dozen questions left with the [blueprint](/questions/tagged/blueprint) tag, but these were enough that I haven't synonymized the two aforementioned tags yet. Should we split this one up into its respective Java/Python/etc topics? Something else? Then synonymize the two when we're done since, evidently, most questions with the tag are about the CSS framework?